# How can I know if an android app is requesting a data connection?

Tags: android, connectivity

I want to create a service to monitor app data usage and log whether the data request can be serviced or not based on the availability of a mobile-data/WiFi connection.

I think I can use the Traffic Stats API to find out which app wants data. But I could not find (yet), an API which can detect connectivity requests.

Please help me find :

Which API can be used to find out if an app is raising any kind of data connectivity request.

And

If Traffic Stats is not an apt way, an elegant method to find out which app is requesting for it?